# Data not being updated in MySQL from VB program

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am trying to get my program to import data entered in the program, to update a table in MySQL. I've looked over the code and did some research and it looks like it should work, but the data isn't being written to the MySQL server. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is my VB code and the MySQL stored procedure.

```
     Public Class OrePriceUpdate
     Dim Mysqlconn As MySqlConnection
     Dim cmd As MySqlCommand

Private Sub Update_Prices_Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Update_Prices_Button.Click
    Mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection()
    Mysqlconn.ConnectionString = "server=xxxxxx;Uid=xxxx;Pwd=xxxxxx;database=xxxx"

    Try
        Mysqlconn.Open()
        cmd = New MySqlCommand()
        cmd.Connection = Mysqlconn
        cmd.CommandText = "update_ore_prices"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@veldspar", Veldspar_Isk.Text)
Catch myerror As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(myerror.Message)
    Finally
        Mysqlconn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

SQL query

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `YHI`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `update_ore_prices`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`YHI`@`%` PROCEDURE `update_ore_prices`(
IN veldspar DECIMAL(10,2)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Ore_Ice_Prices(
    Veldspar
VALUES(
    veldspar);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You open your connection, you create your command object, but you don't actually execute it. Once you've finished adding parameters execute it using:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

For more information try this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL). Particularly there's a section on executing commands:

> Usually, Insert, update and delete are used to write or change data in
>   the database, while Select is used to read data. For this reason, we
>   have different types of methods to execute those queries. The methods
>   are the following:
>
> ```
> ExecuteNonQuery: Used to execute a command that will not return any data, for example Insert, update or delete.
> ExecuteReader: Used to execute a command that will return 0 or more records, for example Select.
> ExecuteScalar: Used to execute a command that will return only 1 value, for example Select Count(*).
> ```